# Probema con agrupacion en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by

Tengo un problema con una consulta, os defino cuál es el objetivo.
Una empresa trabaja de la siguiente forma:
Un cliente realiza 1 pedido de venta con N artículos, seguidamente se realiza el o los pedidos de compra de los artículos reflejados en el pedido de venta.
La consulta que he realizado, me retorna el siguiente resultado:

| P.VENTA | FECHA | CLIENTE | NOMBRE | TOTAL VENTA | P.COMPRA | TOTAL COMPRA | BENEFICIO € | BENEFICIO.P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SF1 | 2023-01-25 | 43000002 | Ramón Bernat | 416 | PC1 | 200 | 216 | 108% |
| SF1 | 2023-01-25 | 43000002 | Ramón Bernat | 416 | PC3 | 54 | 362 | 670% |
| SF2 | 2023-01-25 | 43000002 | Ramón Bernat | 162 | PC2 | 69 | 93 | 135% |

Como podéis ver, se muestra la relación de los pedidos totales y beneficios.
Ahora necesito agrupar por cliente para totalizar el beneficio y mostrar en un solo registro: **Cliente, total venta, total compra, beneficio en € y el porcentaje**, pero como podéis ver en los datos, hay dos pedidos de compra que hacen referencia al mismo pedido de venta, por lo que no puedo hacer una agrupación normal, ya que me sumaría el importe del Pedido de venta tantas veces como enlaces con pedidos de compra tenga y lo que necesito es que me haga el sumatorio de los pedidos de compra, pero no de los de venta, es decir necesito este resultado:

| CLIENTE | NOMBRE | TOTAL VENTA | TOTAL COMPRA | BENEFICIO € | BENEFICIO P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 43000002 | Ramón Bernat | 416 | 254 | 162 | 64% |

(En este resultado estoy obviando el enlace del último registro del ejemplo, ya que con enlaces 1 a 1 no hay problema, solo pretendo mostrar mi problemática cuando tengo mas de un pedido de compra haciendo referencia a un pedido de venta).

No he considerado necesario aportar la consulta que me lleva a este resultado, ya que no tengo problema con ella, solo me gustaría que alguien me ayudara a como enfocar el problema, porque no se me ocurre ya como hacerlo.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No pongas el resultado de una consulta sin poner la consulta. Solo estás ocultando información que puede provocar una solución que no sea óptima y desperdicie recursos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La agrupación que tienes que hacer debiera ser de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT
    PVenta,
    Cliente,
    Nombre,
    MIN([Total Venta]) [Total Venta],
    SUM([Total Compra]) [Total Compra],
    MIN([Total Venta]) - SUM([Total Compra]) [Beneficio €],
    (MIN([Total Venta]) - SUM([Total Compra]))*100.0/SUM([Total Compra]) [Beneficio P]
FROM dbo.Tabla t
GROUP BY 
    PVenta,
    Cliente
;
```

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro, pero por tu ejemplo creo que quieres agrupar por el campo P.VENTA.

La consulta sería algo así

```
SELECT `P.Venta`, Cliente, Nombre, `Total Venta`, SUM(`Total Compra`) AS `Total Compra`, `Total Venta` - SUM(`Total Compra`) AS `Beneficio P`,  FROM pedidos
GROUP BY `P.Venta`
```

Yo usé para la prueba MariaDB, si usas sql server u otro igual hay que modificar la forma de referenciar las columnas, pero la consulta basicamente es así